# How to Restrict to take input in JQuery from a input field Consisting on Alphabets without Space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to take an input from a text field and value should be consisting on alphabets and there should not be any space in between? Kindly let me know how to achieve this? Code is as follows;

```
 $("#xxxx").bind("keyup change", function () {
              $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/ /g,""));
            });
```

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: Put another way: show us your code - what have you tried?

Comment: Now this code although don't allow spaces but it is allowing numeric numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Get to know regexes.  They are fun, and you can test them here: https://regex101.com/

Use a regex in the replace that finds all non-alpha characters:

```
// no-conflict-safe document ready
jQuery(function($) {
  // bind using on to a *class* instead of an id.
  $(".numbers-only").on("keyup blur", function() {
    // use a regex that finds all non-alpha characters
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^a-z]/ig, ''));
  });
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cale_b/602wuwmx/

Notes for improving your code:
1. Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of [bind](http://api.jquery.com/bind/).  (Per the `bind` documentation, *bind was superseded by the .on() method for attaching event handlers to a document since jQuery 1.7, so its use was already discouraged.*)
2. Bind to a *class* rather than an *id*.  In this way, you can make multiple inputs behave this way.

Answer (score 0):

You just check with regex if there is only alphabets:

```
var value = 'asdasd';
var isValid = value.match(/^[a-zA-Z]$/); 
if (isValid) {
   // valid
} else {
   // not valid
}
```